# Can I 'reverse' an S Corporation distribution?

Tags: united-states, accounting, s-corporation, payroll-taxes

I am the sole proprietor and employee of an S Corporation.

I know I'm required to pay myself a reasonable salary.

Say in January the S corporation received $30,000 of revenue from completing a project. In February it made a non-dividend distribution of $20,000 to my personal bank account.

Now it's November. Two questions:

1. Can I send the $20,000 back to the corporation's bank account, and then pay myself this $20,000 as salary (really paying myself ~$23,000-$25,000 of salary which comes to $20k after withholding and payroll taxes)?
2. If #1 is do-able, can I do this as a 'ledger adjustment', i.e. I don't physically send the money back and forth but the net effect is the same, and I pay payroll on the $20,000 the same as if the money physically went back and forth.

Comment: What would be the purpose of putting money back in just to pay it out again?

Comment: basically to pay it out as salary (with payroll taxes) instead of a distribution, to meet reasonable salary requirements

Comment: Ah right, that's in the question I just didn't pay good attention.

Answer (score 5):

You're basically saying that you paid yourself the salary, but didn't pay the necessary payroll taxes. To avoid interest and penalties, you need to file an amended form 941 for that period ([Form 941-X](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i941x#en_US_202204_publink1000300100)) and pay the taxes. The bookkeeping doesn't matter to the IRS as such, and I don't think you need to move money back and forth.

The penalties for willful non-compliance are very steep and potentially criminal. Worth talking to a EA/CPA licensed in your State.

Comment: Gotcha - what distinguishes a payment as salary vs non-dividend distribution? Like what is it that makes the initial payment mis-reported salary vs properly-reported distribution?

Comment: @Claudiu your intent.